# Why can't I log into a beta site that I received an email invitation to?

Tags: bug, status-completed, private-beta

I received an invitation email saying you've granted me *special access* to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com. When I log in, it says "Come back when we're open to the public." It also says:

> p.s. If you committed to support this site on Area 51, you should have an invitation to this beta in your email. It’s important that you follow the link provided in your private beta invite email, because it may contain a special token granting you access. Also, you’ll need to use the same email and login credentials here that you used on Area 51 so we know who you are.

But the link in the email doesn't have any special token; it is just exactly "http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com".

Comment: you have two completely disjoint set of accounts using completely unrelated credentials; stand by, Jarrod will be working on this

Answer (score 6):

Relevant portion:

> ### Also, you’ll need to use the same email and login credentials here that you used on Area 51 so we know who you are.

Your account here is only linked to your Ask Ubuntu account, so I would assume you're using separate info on Area 51.  Your Area 51 account is linked to your Stack Overflow and Server Fault accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you've committed to a proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), you can now log into its closed beta site with any credentials you've used on any of your network accounts.

Just go to your [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current) and click the "my logins" link to view your credentials.